# How to transfer the whole contents of a folder (recursively) from one server to another?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, command-line, files, transfer

I have a `/home/jbruni` folder in a VPS running Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).

I am about to turn this VPS off and move some things from it to a new VPS, also running the same Ubuntu version.

At the moment, I want to move all contents at `/home/jbruni` from the "old" VPS to the new one.

1) I want to **preserve all file permission and ownership settings** (I don't want to use any `chown` or `chmod` after the transfer). [Note: the new VPS already have the same users/groups with same UIDs/GIDs.]

2) I want to **preserve all symlinks** and hardlinks, although I believe there is not a single hardlink in this case. I have lots of symlinks, both for files and for folders, all pointing to locations inside the own `/home/jbruni` folder.

3) I'd really like to **preserve date and times** (mtime, atime, ctime). [If not possible, ok... it is not that bad.]

4) I don't have enough disk space to create a big file containing everything in the "old" VPS prior to transfering it (like a big tarball). Anyway, I may acquire this temporary extra space if  really really needed.

So, what I want is like a "mirror" of the source folder. Is there a way to accomplish this easily? (Or even not so easily?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `rsync`!

```
rsync -azv -e ssh ./localdirectory/ user@otherserver:/remote/dir
```

`-a` is the bad-boy here. It's actually a metaargument that calls `-rlptgoD` which means, amongst other things:

- Recursive
- Preserve symlinks
- Preserve permissions
- Preserve modification times
- Preserve group
- Preserve owner
- And preserves special stuff

It won't preserve hardlinks because hardlinks *are files* (well it's actually a pointer to an inode that stores a filename - but that's what a regular file is too - when you make a hardlink you're just giving an inode an extra filename). This shouldn't be an issue for you because they're quite rare IMO.

`-z` will attempt to compress the data in the stream (speed things up a bit).

`-v` will make sure it's giving you plenty of output.

Comment: Perfect! I am pleased to see it in action right now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just had to figure out from which server should I run the command. :-) It worths mentioning that it is from the **source** server, not the destination.

Comment: You can actually run it from either server. The command is `<source> <target>` so you could run `user@otherserver:/remote/dir ./localdir/`

Comment: Thanks for the improved answer containing the parameter details and for the extra tip in the previous comment. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I would use rsync for that. I believe it's installed by default in Ubuntu, but if it's not, then you can install it from the archives.